# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: pytorch

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I am trying to install `Pytorch Library` on My `Windows 10`, having `Python Version 3.6.9` and using the following command taken from this website :https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#windows-package-manager

> conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c
> pytorch

The installation ended with the following message:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- cuda80
- torchvision==0.2.1
- pytorch==1.0.0

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the `conda` package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Please require solution of the  above problem. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to install pytorch using miniconda 32-bit. I uninstalled it and installed the 64-bit version of miniconda. I was able to install pytorch after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31270708)